# Dimensional analysis with term raised to a power with a unit

Tags: thermodynamics, dimensional-analysis

I've been reading a [paper by Melanie Ott](https://photonics.gsfc.nasa.gov/tva/meldoc/sources1.pdf) and when faced with unfamiliar equations, I like to go through the dimensional analysis to help understand the terms.  However, I realised with this paper that I don't really know how to do this when there are powers involved.

The equation I'm looking at from that paper is this one from the bottom of page 5:

$$
t = c e^{E_a/kT}
$$

Note that $e$ here is electron charge in ($160\times10^{-21}~\mathrm{J/eV}$), **not** the normal $e = 2.718...$

The units of $t$ and $c$ are both seconds, so $e^{E_a/kT}$ must be dimensionless.  $e$ has units $\mathrm{J/eV}$ and $E_a/kT$ has units of $\mathrm{eV/J}$ which looks sort-of logical; however, I'm struggling to get my head round exactly what's happening with this power term to cancel out the units.  If it was simply $e \times E_a / kT$ rather than $e^{E_a/kT}$ it would be obvious but I feel like I'm missing something.

Can anyone offer a simple explanation of how this works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things not right here:

1. $E_a/kT$ is unitless, as $kT$ also has energy units. Note that $1 \, J \approx 6\times 10^{18} \; eV $ and
2. you are not raising $e$ as in the electron charge to this power in the paper. It is $e \approx 2.71$, the base of the natural logarithm.

So in the end, the factor is a unitless value raised to a unitless power.

The equation is the normal equation for a random decay/linear kinetics, exactly the same equation as you would use in radioactivity for example.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you.  I'd missed that $eV$ is equivalent to $J$ in unit terms, which in itself is enough to explain the issue.  Your point #2 surprises me: immediately under the equation on page 5, the paper states "e is electron charge = 1.6 * 10-19 joules/eV".  It seems strange that it would say this when e is actually 2.71 (I found it an odd choice of letter when I first read the paper, as it could so easily confuse).

Comment: I am also surprised by that comment in the paper. I don't think it makes sense - they also explicitly call it an [Arrhenius equation, which, again, contains Euler's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrhenius_equation). I'm inclined to call it a mistake.